# Plugin or library to add local notifications on xamarin cross-platform mobile app?

Tags: xamarin, notifications, nuget, cross-platform, localnotification

I am pretty new to xamarin. I am developing an app where I need to schedule local notifications and show them on a specific time (even if the app is not running), and when user clicks on the notification, it has to go to a specific activity (lets say "notification activity"). 
While browsing the internet, I have come across different plugins but none of them has all the features that are needed.

**Good Nugetplugins that I found**

- https://github.com/aritchie/notifications
- https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

**Required features**

- Schedule notifications
- Show scheduled notifications even if the app is not running
- when user clicks on the notification, app opens into a specific activity

**Mobile Cross-platforms**

- Android
- iOS
- Windows phone

**Every help is welcome!**

Comment: what you mean by Show scheduled notifications even if the app is not running !

Comment: It looks like the plugins you have listed will do what you want, you just have to handle the notification pressed inside each of the target platforms.. here's a link for iOS
https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/handling-push-notifications-in-xamarin-ios-when-app-is-closed/

Comment: @HoussemDbira "not running" = app is not in the foreground or is terminated.

Comment: @chriszumberge Can you give me an example of the "notification pressed" handeling in android? Would be very grateful !

Comment: There's some background information here.. should be enough to get you started or at least point your research in the right direction
https://xamarinhelp.com/push-notifications-lifecycle/

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.LocalNotification

But it does not support Windows phone only support Android and iOS.

It has:

1. Schedule notifications
2. Show scheduled notifications even if the app is not running
3. when user clicks on the notification, can subscribe to it.